# Resample pandas times series that contains elapsed time values

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series data in the format shown on the bottom of this post.

I want to re-sample the data to 30 minute intervals but i need the Time in State values to be split accordingly to the correct interval (these values are expressed in whole seconds).

Now imagine for a certain row the Time in State is 2342 seconds (more than 30 minutes) and say the start time is at 08:22:00.

```
User    Start Date  Start Time  State   Time in State (secs)
J.Doe   03-02-2014  08:22:00    A       2342
```

When the re-sample is done I need for the Time in State to be split accordingly into the  periods it overflows into, like this:

```
User    Start Date  Time Period State   Time in State (secs)
J.Doe   03-02-2014  08:00:00    A       480
J.Doe   03-02-2014  08:30:00    A       1800
J.Doe   03-02-2014  09:00:00    A       62
```

480+1800+62 = 2342

I'm completely lost on how to achieve this in pandas...I would appreciate any help :-)

**Source data format:**

```
User    Start Date  Start Time  State   Time in State (secs)
J.Doe   03-02-2014  07:58:00    A       36
J.Doe   03-02-2014  07:59:00    A       43
J.Doe   03-02-2014  08:00:00    A       59
J.Doe   03-02-2014  08:01:00    A       32
J.Doe   03-02-2014  08:21:00    A       15
J.Doe   03-02-2014  08:22:00    B       3
J.Doe   03-02-2014  08:22:00    A       2342
J.Doe   03-02-2014  09:01:00    B       1
J.Doe   03-02-2014  09:01:00    A       375
J.Doe   03-02-2014  09:07:00    B       3
J.Doe   03-02-2014  09:07:00    A       6408
J.Doe   03-02-2014  10:54:00    B       2
J.Doe   03-02-2014  10:54:00    A       116
J.Doe   03-02-2014  10:58:00    B       2
J.Doe   03-02-2014  10:58:00    A       122
J.Doe   03-02-2014  10:58:00    A       12
J.Doe   03-02-2014  11:00:00    B       2
J.Doe   03-02-2014  11:00:00    A       3417
J.Doe   03-02-2014  11:57:00    B       3
J.Doe   03-02-2014  11:57:00    A       120
J.Doe   03-02-2014  11:59:00    C       165
J.Doe   03-02-2014  12:02:00    B       3
J.Doe   03-02-2014  12:02:00    A       7254
```

Comment: Could you clarify why and how 2342 in your example is partitioned into  480, 1600, and 62?

Comment: I think the trick is to extract start and end times and resample, I think there is a cookbook example for what's on and off at each period, this is a (fiddly) extension of those examples...

Comment: @Paul H You are right maybe that wasn't clear enough. Basically because the 2342 seconds start at 8:22 so when deciding where they belong in each half an hour period of the day we get 8 mins (480 secs) that fall in the 8:00 to 8:30 period (because the State started at 8:22 there are only 8 minutes left in that period). 30 mins (1800 secs) that fall in the 8:30 to 9:00 period and the remaining 62 secs in the 9:00 to 9:30 period.

Comment: @Andy Hayden Could you possibly link me the cookbook example? I went through this list and nothing seems to be what i need http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html

Comment: @pmanacas will have a look later, it's similar, for now I've an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would first create Start and End columns (as datetime64 objects):

```
In [11]: df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'] + ' ' + df['Start Time'])

In [12]: df['End'] = df['Start'] + df['Time in State (secs)'].apply(pd.offsets.Second)

In [13]: row = df.iloc[6, :]

In [14]: row
Out[14]: 
User                                  J.Doe
Start Date                       03-02-2014
Start Time                         08:22:00
State                                     A
Time in State (secs)                   2342
Start                   2014-03-02 08:22:00
End                     2014-03-02 09:01:02
Name: 6, dtype: object
```

One way to get the split times is to resample from Start and End, merge, and use diff:

```
def split_times(row):
    y = pd.Series(0, [row['Start'], row['End']])
    splits = y.resample('30min').index + y.index  # this fills in middle and sorts too
    res = -splits.to_series().diff(-1)
    if len(res) > 2: res = res[1:-1]
    elif len(res) == 2: res = res[1:] 
    return res.astype(int).resample('30min').astype(np.timedelta64)  # hack to resample again

In [16]: split_times(row)
Out[16]: 
2014-03-02 08:22:00   00:08:00
2014-03-02 08:30:00   00:30:00
2014-03-02 09:00:00   00:01:02
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [17]: df.apply(split_times, 1)
Out[17]: 
    2014-03-02 07:30:00  2014-03-02 08:00:00  2014-03-02 08:30:00  2014-03-02 09:00:00  2014-03-02 09:30:00  2014-03-02 10:00:00  2014-03-02 10:30:00  2014-03-02 11:00:00  2014-03-02 11:30:00  2014-03-02 12:00:00  2014-03-02 12:30:00  2014-03-02 13:00:00  2014-03-02 13:30:00  2014-03-02 14:00:00
0              00:00:36                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
1              00:00:43                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
2                   NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
3                   NaT             00:00:32                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
4                   NaT             00:00:15                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
5                   NaT             00:00:03                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
6                   NaT             00:08:00             00:30:00             00:01:02                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
7                   NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:00:01                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
8                   NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:06:15                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
9                   NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:00:03                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
10                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:23:00             00:30:00             00:30:00             00:23:48                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
11                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:00:02                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
12                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:01:56                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
13                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:00:02                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
14                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:02:00             00:00:02                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
15                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:00:12                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
16                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
17                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:26:57                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
18                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:00:03                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
19                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:02:00                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
20                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:01:00             00:01:45                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
21                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:00:03                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT
22                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT                  NaT             00:28:00             00:30:00             00:30:00             00:30:00             00:02:54
```

To replace the NaTs with 0 it looks like you have to do some fiddling in 0.13.1 (this may already be fixed up in master, otherwise is a bug):

```
res2 = df.apply(split_times, 1).astype(int)
# hack to replace NaTs with 0
res2.where(res2 != -9223372036854775808, 0).astype(np.timedelta64)
# to just get the seconds
seconds = res2.where(res2 != -9223372036854775808, 0) / 10 ** 9
```

Comment: When i try to do `df['End'] = df['Start'] + df['Time in State (secs)'].apply(pd.offsets.Second)` I get an error: `ValueError: cannot operate on a series with out a rhs of a series/ndarray of typ
e datetime64[ns] or a timedelta`

Comment: NumPy 1.7.1 Pandas 0.11.0 (I'm limited to Portable Python due to admin rights restrictions :-(

Comment: Ok I managed to upgrade to Pandas 0.13.1 numpy 1.8.0 I can now run your example code up to `split_times(row)` which returns: `TypeError: cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]`

Comment: @pmanacas are you on Windows? I think it's fussier and you need to do astype(np.int64). ps. I recommend using Anaconda for installing without admin rights.

Comment: Yes i had managed to install using Anaconda :-) I can now run your code example (using np.int64) However I need the final output to still be split by 'User' and 'State'. Your help has been excellent so far :-) sorry for the noobness

Comment: @pmanacas I suggest splitting first... one way is to [g.get_group(x) for x in g.groups] or `{label: res.iloc[ind] for label, inds in g.indices.items()}` not sure if easier way, depends what you want to do with it.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand your last comment. I was hoping to get a final data output in the format of my second code block in the original question. with one row per User / per Day / per 30 min period / per State / with sum of seconds

Comment: I would actually do something like: `df.iloc[g.groups[('J.Doe', 'A')]].apply(split_times, 1).astype(int).replace(-9223372036854775808, np.nan).stack() // 10 ** 9` (although it looks awful).